# reactjs redirection after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating an app in Reactjs. I have app.js, dashboard.js and login.js.

in my app.js i have a link to login page. i wanted to redict to dashboard page from login page. In my login, I am making a call to backend service and validating user credentails.  I have the following code in `login.js`

```
   request.post(
         options,
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log('redirecting');

                // browserHistory.push('/dashboard')
                // ( <Redirect to={{
                //   pathname: '/dashboard'
                // }}/>)
                // this.props.history.push('/dashboard');

                <Redirect to='./dashboard' />  // redirection is not working here 

            }else{
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    );
```

When i enter user credentials, After the validation i could see redirecting message in console however the page is not redirecting.

I am using `react-router-dom`. Can you please help me to identify what went wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put jsx code inside a function. jsx code work inside render function and on the click of `<Redirect to='./dashboard' />` will redirect to dashboard page. But you are trying to redirect programmatically.

Use `browserHistory.push('/dashboard')` for redirect from a function.

This is a reference [Navigating Outside of Components](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)

Comment: Is this for version 3 or 4? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may only use `<Redirect>` as a rendered element from within one of your components (not from within a JS function).

Therefore, from your `login` page where you are calling this function how about setting a variable after the response from the server to indicate whether the user was successfully logged in and then, based on its value, display the `<Redirect>`.

For example,

```
request.post(
    options,
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log('redirecting');

            this.setState({
              isLoggedIn: true
            })

        }else{
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
);
```

and in your `render` method:

```
if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
  return <Redirect to='./dashboard' />
}
return (
  // If the user is not logged in, return the usual login page...
)
```